# CakePHP 2.0 not using my Ajax layout

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am in progress of migrating an app from CakePHP 1.3 to 2.0, and have noticed a problem with the ajax parts of my app, in that CakePHP is serving up Ajax responses with the `default.ctp` layout, and not my `ajax.ctp`.

Is there anything I need to do in particular to get the ajax layout to work? It's currently located in `View/Layouts/ajax.ctp` with my `default.ctp` which works fine.

Comment: I assume you have `$this->layout = 'ajax'` in your method?

Comment: No, as I didn't need it in 1.3/. Am I going to have to check in my beforeFilter for `$this->request->is('ajax')` ?

Comment: That should work (I'm surprised you say you didn't need it in 1.3; I assumed it was required to work with ajax layout). beforeFilter should be a fairly decent approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you specify the layout in beforeRender in your controller or app_controller? If so, an easy hack would be `$this->autoLayout = false;`; or better: call `$this->render('view_name','ajax');` at the end of your action.

You probably use RequestHandler (I heard it will automatically use ajax layout for ajax requests, but I rarely use it, so I don't know).