# CakePHP ajax call loads wrong layout

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, menu, nested

I've been working in CakePHP and I got the following problem.
I have a admin page (AdminsController) with 1 view and 1 method, Index.
The index view includes hard-coded links to other controllers and views. 
I did assign a class to all those links to load a DIV over the admin content with the content of the view in it. Via this script:

```
$(".cmsPage").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            $("#admin_wrapper", "#admin_close", "#admin_content").fadeIn('slow');
            $("#admin_content").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Now in one of those views of the **pages** controller, **pages/overview** I made an ajax call to an other method in the same controller, **update_menu**. This method has a view also. This is what currently have in my controller/method.

```
public function update_menu(){
        $this->layout = '';
        foreach($this->request->data as $menu){
            //$this->layout = 'ajax';
            foreach($menu as $id => $submenu){
                $saveData = array('id' => $id, 'submenu' => $submenu);
                $this->Page->save($saveData);
                $this->render('update_menu','ajax');
            }
        }
    }
```

The Admin controller has a **Admin** layout so does the **overview**.
This is what happens when I try to get the data from update_menu. (inside $(document).ready(function(){}); )

```
$("#save_page").click(function(){
    toArray();
    return false;
 });
```

function toArray() (outside $(document).ready(function(){});)

```
 function toArray()
{
    var serialized = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('serialize');
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update_menu',
    data: serialized,
    success: function(data){
        $("#result").html('De pagina\'s zijn opgeslagen!');
    }
    });
}
```

What I get back in the console is the whole render of `admins/index`. view& layout.

What do I need to do to get the view result instead of the `admins/index`.

For the information, I'd use http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/forum/categories/releases.

Greetings,
Harm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 2.0 not using my Ajax layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898439/cakephp-2-0-not-using-my-ajax-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is ajax call for this, you dont need to load any layout in your action
try this.

```
$this->layout = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your layout to the ajax layout:

```
$this->layout = "ajax";
```

or alternatively, automate it by including the RequestHandler component in your AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    "RequestHandler"
);
```

Comment: Did tried both and both at the same time. But the result is that i get the admin's index VIEW not even the layout...